# Java project in IntelliJ is error free but compilation fails via Maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I've worked my way through the [example hello world dropwizard](http://dropwizard.codahale.com/getting-started/) project which appears error free in IntelliJ  (I'm an Eclipse veteran but new to IntelliJ) but compilation fails via maven.

[image: IntelliJ console]

The source directory contains:

```
/src/main/java/com/example/helloworld/HelloWorldConfiguration.java
/src/main/java/com/example/helloworld/HelloWorldService.java
```

where `HelloWorldService` looks like:

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import com.example.helloworld.resources.HelloWorldResource;
import com.example.helloworld.health.TemplateHealthCheck;
import com.yammer.dropwizard.Service;
import com.yammer.dropwizard.config.Bootstrap;
import com.yammer.dropwizard.config.Environment;

public class HelloWorldService extends Service<HelloWorldConfiguration> {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new HelloWorldService().run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(Bootstrap<HelloWorldConfiguration> bootstrap) {
        bootstrap.setName("hello-world");
    }

    @Override
    public void run(HelloWorldConfiguration configuration,
                    Environment environment) {
        final String template = configuration.getTemplate();
        final String defaultName = configuration.getDefaultName();
        environment.addResource(new HelloWorldResource(template, defaultName));
        environment.addHealthCheck(new TemplateHealthCheck(template));
    }

}
```

and maven is coming back with:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project my-project: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/markdsievers/IdeaProjects/dropwizard/src/main/java/com/example/helloworld/HelloWorldService.java:[9,48] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class HelloWorldConfiguration
[ERROR] /Users/markdsievers/IdeaProjects/dropwizard/src/main/java/com/example/helloworld/HelloWorldService.java:[15,38] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class HelloWorldConfiguration
[ERROR] location: class com.example.helloworld.HelloWorldService
[ERROR] /Users/markdsievers/IdeaProjects/dropwizard/src/main/java/com/example/helloworld/HelloWorldService.java:[20,21] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class HelloWorldConfiguration
[ERROR] location: class com.example.helloworld.HelloWorldService
```

where the `pom.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.helloworld</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yammer.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <!-- use UTF-8 for everything -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I get the same error from maven if the compile goal is run from the command line or within IntelliJ. Source root (/src/main/java) is set in IntelliJ and no amount of cleaning and recompiling has had any effect.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: It would be easier to reproduce the situation if you included the full source for `HelloWorldConfiguration` too. (I ran into other compilation problems related to that. Didn't spot any obvious problems with your setup.)

Comment: Extremely "too localized" as the answer proves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue... `HelloWorldConfiguration` did not have a `.java` extension. Pretty evil IMO, IDE is treating it as a valid java file and was created via the New Java Class (or must not have or something went wrong). Anyways, probably need to enable view of file extensions.

Comment: That's odd, but nice that you got it working. (I do find it hard to believe though that IDEA would leave out the ".java" extension when creating a class normally through IDEA UI.)

Comment: @Jonik Yes, thoroughly confused how it got into (and remained in) that state and annoying that IntelliJ represented the environment as error free. Thanks for looking, sorry for the extremely localized problem.